# turn the result table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a schema in Mysql database:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
ID int,
Country varchar(50),
category varchar(10)
); 

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,'USA','A');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2,'USA','A');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3,'USA','B');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4,'Canada','A');
```

with this query :

```
SELECT country,count(category),category FROM test GROUP BY country,category;
```

I get this result :

```
+---------+-------+----------+
| Country | count | category |
+---------+-------+----------+
| Canada  |     1 | A        |
| USA     |     2 | A        |
| USA     |     1 | B        |
+---------+-------+----------+
```

but I want get like this result  :

```
+---------+---+---+
| Country | A | B |
+---------+---+---+
| Canada  | 1 | 0 |
| USA     | 2 | 1 |
+---------+---+---+
```

Any advice will be nice. Thanks

here is my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2257f/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT country, 
       sum(case when category = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
       sum(case when category = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as B
FROM test 
GROUP BY country;
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2257f/3)

Comment: and If I don't know wich categories I have ??

Comment: Then this is going to be harder. Look for *Pivot*.